# Show that $\mathcal{A}_+$ is an algebra which separates points and does not vanish in $\mathbb{T}$, but is not dense in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}_+ = \mathop{\mathrm{lin}}\{e^{inx} \colon n \geq 0\} \subset \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$. Here, $\mathop{\mathrm{lin}}\{\cdot\}$ signifies linear combinations of the argument, and $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle. I believe I have answered the question, but I would appreciate some feedack on my answer. I also guess the easy way to do it would be to point out that $\mathcal{A}_+$ is not self-adjoint and refer to Stone-Weierstrass.

My answer:

To show that $\mathcal{A}_+$ is an algebra it is sufficient to show that $a, b \in \mathcal{A}_+ \implies ab \in \mathcal{A}_+$, as from the definition of the algebra, it is clearly closed under addition and scalar multiplication. This is easily seen from the fact that $e^k e^j = e^{k+j}$, and so $\mathcal{A}_+$ is an algebra. To see that it separates points, let $x, y \in \mathbb{T}$, $x \neq y$. Then $e^x \neq e^y$. To see that it does not vanish, observe that $0 \neq e^0 \in \mathcal{A}_+$.

However, it is not dense in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$, as $e^{-ix}$ is not a limit point of any sequence in $\mathcal{A}_+$.

It is particularly this final paragraph I am unsure about. Can I state it so simply, or should it be more rigorous, even if it seems pretty clear-cut?

Comment: what is  $A_+$ ?

Comment: Woops, it was originally defined in the title, but I had to remove it as the title was too long and I forgot to add it to the body of the question. It should be fixed now.

Comment: notice that $e^{inx}$ may be equal to $e^{iny}$ even for $x\ne y$

Comment: and the last paragraph should be a lot more rigorous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did is fine. We only need a proof that $x\mapsto e^{-ix}$ is not a limit point of ${\cal A}_+$.

Here the idea
$$\int_{\partial D}z^n\>dz=0\quad(n\geq0),\qquad \int_{\partial D}{dz\over z}=2\pi i$$
should come to our help. In the setup of your question this means that
$$\int_{\mathbb T}e^{int}\cdot e^{it}\>dt=0\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)\cdot e^{it}\>dt=0\qquad\forall f\in{\cal A}_+\ .$$
On the other hand
$$\int_{\mathbb T}e^{-it}\cdot e^{it}\>dt=2\pi\ .$$